# Knockout Binds Not Working On Second Generation of Dynamic Content

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am working on a project that uses knockout and MVC4.  I have some code that generates a dynamic jquery dialog that populates itself with knockout data:

```
$("#manage-pros").click(function () {
$("<div>")
    .attr("data-bind", "template: { name: 'pro-template' }")
    .dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Manage Pros",
        width: 700,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "Save Changes",
                'data-bind': 'click: saveChanges',
                click: function () { }
            },
            {
                text: "Cancel",
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        ],
        close: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            ko.cleanNode($(this));
        },
        open: function () {
            ko.applyBindings(new ProViewModel());
            $("input[type=button]").button();
        }
    });
});
```

Pro template looks like this:

```
    <div class="modal-form" id="pro-template">
        <div class="form-element">
            <label>Add New Pro</label>
            <input data-bind="value: newProText" class="textbox ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            <input type="button" data-bind="click: addPro" value="Add Pro" />
        </div>
        <table style="border-collapse: collapse;" class="ui-widget ui-corner-all">
            <tr class="ui-widget-header ui-dialog-header" style="">
                <td style="width: 75px; padding: 5px;">Modified</td>
                <td style="width: 425px; padding: 5px;">Pro Name</td>
                <td style="width: 100px; padding: 5px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: pros">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        <span data-bind="fadeVisible: name.hasChanged()"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check left-icon"></span></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input data-bind="value: name, visible: editingText(), hasfocus: editingText" class="textbox ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                        <span data-bind="text: name, visible: !editingText(), click: textClick"></span>
                    </td>


                    <td>
                        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removePro">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

What I am finding is that everything works fantastic the first time that the dynamic content is added to the DOM, however, if I press escape or close the dialog, my "click to edit" functionality does not work.  I tried to get this into a jsfiddle, however, I think that it's a bit too complex.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.... I feel dumb now.  I wasn't destroying the dialog fully.

```
$(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
```

Added the above line to the close handler on the dialog and boom, works great!

Answer (score 0):

When binding events to things created by knockout you should use .live instead of .bind to pickup newly created DOM elements